# Differentiation and Uniform Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

I've just read the following theorem in some lecture notes:

> Let $f_n : [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f_n'$
>   continuous for all $n$. Suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $f_n'$
>   converges uniformly on $[a,b]$. Then $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is
>   differentiable and $f'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'(x)$ for all $x
> \in [a,b]$.

I'm struggling to understand what $f'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ means in this context.

Does it mean

a) $f_n'(x)$ tends to $f'(x)$ just as a sequence of real numbers for each $x \in [a,b]$

b) $f_n'(x)$ converges pointwise to $f'(x)$

c) $f_n'(x)$ converges uniformly (and so also pointwise) to $f'(x)$

I would be very grateful for any help,

Jack

Comment: (c). The point is that the limit is $f'$, and not another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the author says, they mean to say (a): $f'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x)$. The "for all $x$ is implied". (a) and (b) are definitionally the same, so (b) is also true.

But wait! $f'_n$ converges uniformly to *something* by hypothesis. Suppose $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $g$. Then $f_n'$ converges pointwise to $g$ and to $f'$ so $g = f'$ by uniqueness of pointwise limits. In other words, $f_n'$ uniformly converges to $f'$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I see $f'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'(x)$, should I be thinking of $f_n'(x)$ and $f'(x)$ as real numbers, or as functions?

Comment: In most analysis textbooks, whenever you see $f(x)$, you should think "the real number achieved by evaluating $f$ at $x$". $x$ may be arbitrary (such as "for all $x \in [a,b]$"), but you should still think of $f(x)$ as a real number. When $f$ has no argument, then you should think of the function. $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f$ would imply to me that $f_n$ converges to $f$ (of which there are [many flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_convergence_(annotated_index)), uniform and pointwise just being two)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of derivatives converge uniformly (and hence to their pointwise limit). So the answer is (c) and hence in particular (b) and (a) follow.